# Extract a string betwen two characters of bigger string with "cut" or "sed"

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple variable string wich come in this form :
**tag=v1.0.2-15** , or **tag=v2.0.2-15** ....

I wanna extract from it the part just after **"v"** and before **"-"** to obtain always the number part ***(= betwen "v" and "_")***

this: **1.0.2**

I used:

```
$ echo (tag=v1.0.2-15 | sed -n '/tag=v/,/-/p')
```

and

```
$ echo (tag=v1.0.2-15 | cut -d'v' -f 2)
```

but that didn't work for the moment.

**Any other simple solutions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to remove the parts before the `v` and after the `-`, using sed:

```
$ sed 's/.*v\|-.*//g' <<<'tag=v1.0.2-15'
1.0.2
```

This matches anything followed by a `v`, or anything after a `-` and replaces with nothing, leaving you with the part you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` `regEx` with the `~` operator

```
string="tag=v1.0.2-15"
[[ $string =~ ^.*v([[:graph:]]+)-.*$ ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
1.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution using grep could look like this:
`echo 'tag=v1.0.2-15' |grep -oP '(?<=v).+(?=-)'`

Comment: also perfect , this one

Answer (score 1):

Use `v` and `-` as a column separator and print second column:

```
awk -F'[v-]' '{print $2}' <<< 'tag=v1.0.2-15'
```

Output:

```
1.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simplified version of `grep` look around.

```
echo 'tag=v1.0.2-15' | grep -oP 'v\K.*?[^-]+'
1.0.2
```

Using `sed` back refrencing:

```
echo 'tag=v1.0.2-15' |sed -r 's/(^.+v)(.+)(-.*)/\2/g'
1.0.2
```